# How to simulate a true browser with Google API for search?

Tags: php, curl, google-api

Currently I'm using something like this bit of code:

```
$tracks[0] = 'insert popular random song here';
$query = urlencode($tracks[0]." download 4shared");
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=".$query;
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

echo $json->responseData->results[0]->url."<br/>";
echo $json->responseData->results[1]->url."<br/>";
echo $json->responseData->results[2]->url;
```

When I search for "chop suey download 4shared" on google from my browser it returns me some 4shared download pages, but when I the method listed above, it returns me some random links from soundcloud and searchs from 4shared, which is completely useless for my purposes. I tried it on Firefox, Chrome and Chrome Incognito

How do I get same results I get on browser using Google API search?

**EDIT**

Partially solved it by changing its query:

```
$query = "site:4shared.com+".str_replace(' ', '+', $track[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

You get different results from a browser search because Google generally knows who you are and tailors its search results to be more applicable to *you*. If you do the search from another person's browser you will get yet different results.

When you run the query via API on what I assume is your server Google doesn't have your profile, or likely any profile, and returns a result set based on that.

This is called a [Filter Bubble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble) and can be slightly infuriating once you know you're in one.

Comment: Even in Chrome Incognito mode?

Comment: Potentially. Incognito mode doesn't change your IP address.